# Why gravititional waves can't pass the speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

The universe can expand faster than light, while gravitational wave are the transmission of the distortion of space. Why can't they be faster than light, what's the difference between these two movements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If space can expand faster than light why can't gravitational wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245413/)