# Gravitational waves and their properties

Tags: interference, gravitational-waves

To clarify my question. I wanted to ask, "how do I figure out the interference of 2 different gravitational waves?" If we were to spin 2 black holes very quickly and take a cross section of the space, what would we see? Will there be wave fronts. Basically, what I want to ask is that, if the universe was in a ball and you were looking at it from the outside, what would gravitational waves look like? Do they have an amplitude or wave length and if so, how do you figure out what those are, given that you know the mass of the 2 rotating black holes.

Comment: which question?  Is this an edit to a previous question?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/713211/how-do-gravitational-waves-propagate

Comment: @annav then this one should be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an edit to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713211/36194 rather than a new stand-alone question.

Comment: Have a look at this video https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v3 of black hole mergers, the animations using the observation of gravitational waves by the LIGO experiment. https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/what-are-gw